# How to show the button on click value?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a beginner at programming.

When I click the button,
The value of the button...
I want it to be displayed as input.

And, when i click it several times,
The corresponding value is added.
I want to mark it.

I'm searching the Internet, but it's not working.
Please help me. Thank you.

```
        <script>
                $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#myform input').on('change',function(){
                var cvalue=$("[type='button']:onclick").val();
                $('#cvalue').val($("[type='button']:onclick").val());
                });
                });
        </script>         <div class="inputdiv">
                <input type="text" id="cvalue" class="money">
        </div>
                <button class="button1" type = "button" value="100,000">100,000</button>
                <button class="button1" type = "button" value="200,000">200,000</button>
                <button class="button1" type = "button" value="300,000">300,000</button>
                <button class="button1" type = "button" value="500,000">500,000</button>
                <button class="button1" type = "button" value="1,000,000">1,000,000</button>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this could help you:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myform button').on('click', function() {
        $('#cvalue').val($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>The button Element</h1>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    var value = $(this).attr("value");
    $('#cvalue').val(value);
  });
});
</script>    
<div class="inputdiv">
 <input type="text" id="cvalue" class="money">
</div>
  <button class="button1" type = "button" value="100,000">100,000</button>
  <button class="button1" type = "button" value="200,000">200,000</button>
  <button class="button1" type = "button" value="300,000">300,000</button>
  <button class="button1" type = "button" value="500,000">500,000</button>
  <button class="button1" type = "button" value="1,000,000">1,000,000</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Use this approach.

Answer (score 1):

Vanilla Javascript Solution:

After clicking on any button you provided, the value of the clicked button will be copied to the input.

```js
"use strict";
let input = document.getElementById("cvalue");
let button = document.querySelectorAll(".button1");
button.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener("click", () => {
    input.value = item.value;
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="inputdiv">
  <input type="text" id="cvalue" class="money" />
</div>
<form>
  <button class="button1" type="button" value="100,000">100,000</button>
  <button class="button1" type="button" value="200,000">200,000</button>
  <button class="button1" type="button" value="300,000">300,000</button>
  <button class="button1" type="button" value="500,000">500,000</button>
  <button class="button1" type="button" value="1,000,000">1,000,000</button>
</form>
```